# How to get related/up next videos using YouTube API ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

I would like to get related/up next videos using YouTube API in iOS. I have the videoID but i don't know how to query the related videos/up next videos of the videoID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) call with the `relatedToVideoId` parameter.